# Como insertar una instancia de un modelo a un request de laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

necesito ayuda.
Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo este método: `public function store(StoreTicket $request, User $user)`.
Lo que quiero es pasar la instancia de ese user al request StoreTicket.

Este es el store:

```php
public function store(StoreTicket $request, User $user)
    {

        if ((int)$request->term_accepted === 0) {
            return $this->errorResponse('Debe aceptar los términos y condiciones del servicio para continuar', 409);
        }

        $data = $request->all();
        $data['user_id'] = $user->id;
        $data['state_id'] = State::where('processes', State::PROCESS_1)->first()->id_state;

        // Obtener el domiciliario con menos tickets.
        $domiciliary = (new DomiciliaryTicketController())->domiciliaryWithoutTicket($data);
        if ($domiciliary === false) {
            return $this->showMessage('No hay domociliarios disponibles para esa hora.');
        }
        $data['domiciliary_id'] = $domiciliary->id_domiciliary;
        $ticket = Ticket::create($data);
        return $this->showOne($ticket);
    }
```

Este es mi TicketStore:

```php
public function rules()
    {
        $towId = PickupAddress::findOrFail($this->pickup_address_id)->neighborhood->town_id;
        $ruleInTime = (new TicketController())->hoursAvailable($this->pickup_date, $towId)->getOriginalContent();
        return [
            'pickup_date' => [
                'date', 'required',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    //Si en un día menor al actual
                    if ($value < now()->toDateString()) {
                        $fail($attribute. ' debe no puede ser un día menor a hoy');
                    }
                    //Si es un día mayor a 15 días a partir del día actual
                    if (now()->diffInDays($value) > 15){
                        $fail($attribute . ' no puede ser mayor a 15 días a partir de hoy');
                    }
                },
            ],
            'pickup_time' => [
                'required',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    $timeFormat = preg_match('/^(\d\d):00:00$/', $value, $matches);
                    if ($timeFormat !== 1) {
                        $fail($attribute.' no es una hora válida.');
                        return;
                    }
                    if ($matches[1] > 23){
                        $fail($attribute.' Debe ser una hora válida del día');
                    }
                },
                Rule::in(is_array($ruleInTime) ? [] : $ruleInTime['times'])
            ],
            'term_accepted' => [
                'required', 'numeric',
                Rule::in([0, 1])
            ],
            'pickup_address_id' => [
                'required',
                Rule::in($user->pickupAddresses->pluck('id')->all())
            ],
            'id_imei' => [
                'required',
                Rule::in($user->imei->pluck('id_imei')->all())
            ]
        ];
    }
```

Quero que la validación en la key pickup_address_id me funcione con el user que está en el store.

Comment: Creería que en el FormRequest podrías acceder al modelo que usas en el model binding con `$this->user`. Lo que no entiendo es que es `pickupAddresses`. ¿Es una relación?

Comment: Si, el pickupAddress es una relación con user.

Comment: Prueba si te funciona de esta manera `Rule::in($this->user->pickupAddresses()->pluck('id')->toArray())`.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que $this->user es la instancia del usuario que está autenticado en ese momento, yo necesito la isntancia del usuario que hay en el sotre.

Comment: Cierto. ¿Que tal con `$this->route('user')->pickupAddresses()->pluck('id')->toArray()`?

Comment: Excelente amigo, gracias, no sabia que se bindeaba la ruta así. Muy buena respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para casi cualquier otro caso, podrías acceder al modelo que usas en el model binding usando la llave del bind, por ejemplo, si vincularas el modelo Product: `$router->model('product', '\App\Product')` podrías obtener una instancia de ese modelo con `$this->product`.

Pero para el caso del modelo `User`, las cosas cambian, pues si haces `$this->user`, te estarás refiriendo al `User` que hizo el request, y no al del model binding.

Entonces, para aludir al User que se instancias por el parámetro que viene en la uri de la ruta, puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
$this->route('user')
```

Que al estar enlazado en el model binding, te devolverá la instancia de ese User, y no al que hizo el request.

Por lo que tu regla podría quedar así:

```
Rule::in($this->route('user')->pickupAddresses()->pluck('id')->toArray())
```

Comment: Gracias bro, muy bien, lo que no entiendo mucho es donde hago lo del binding del ejemplo de Product, ```$router->model('product', '\App\Product')``` , dónde agrego esto, o eso lo hace laravel automáticamente.

Comment: Sí sí, eso lo hace laravel. En tu caso lo estás definiendo en el método strore del controlador `public function store(StoreTicket $request, User $user) { ...`